# min-width CSS Media Query in IE8+

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, media-queries

I am looking at calling different CSS for desktop and iPad browsers.

For desktop, I am using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:1000px)" href="desktop.css">
```

and for iPad, I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (device-width:768px)" href="desktop.css">
```

When I say desktop browsers, I am referring to IE8 and above, FF4+, Safari 5+ on MAC

But for some reasons, the desktop CSS does not get applied in IE8.

Please suggest the best approach such that I can clearly separate desktop/iPad and also it would work on all desktop browsers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@testndtv; `mediaquery` is not work in IE. for this you have to  use [Response.js](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/respondjs_fast_css3_media_queries_for_internet_explorer_6_8_and_more/)

Comment: May be you asked this question second time check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add
`<!--[if IE ]><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="desktop.css"><![endif]-->` to you `<head>` tag.

Comment: So in a way speaking, I'll need to add 2 <link> statements for desktop browsers ....<!--[if IE ]><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="desktop.css"><![endif]--><link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:1000px)" href="desktop.css"> 

One would work for IE and others for all desktop browsers..