# Internet Explorer 8 using retina pixelratio media query

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, sass, media-queries, retina

I'm building a responsive website with SASS/Compass, and I'm including retina icons (using  generated sprites). I include the icons in my .scss with a mixin.

My retina icons mixin:

```
// Retina icons
@mixin sprite-background($name, $xpos: 0px, $ypos: 0px, $xpos2x: $xpos, $ypos2x: $ypos, $size: image-width(sprite-file($icons, $name))) {
  background-image: sprite-url($icons);
  background-position: sprite-position($icons, $name, $xpos, $ypos);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;

  @media all and ($pixel-ratio) {
    @if (sprite-position($icons, $name) != sprite-position($icons2x, $name)) {
      background-position: $xpos2x $ypos2x;
    }
    @include background-size($size auto);
    background-image: sprite-url($icons2x);
  }
}
```

Variable:

```
$pixel-ratio: "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5";
```

Usage:

```
.selector {
  @include sprite-background(clock_small, 0px, 2px, 0px, -1013px, 45px);
}
```

The problem I have is that Internet Explorer 8 is using my retina sprite as `background-image`, and fails on the `background-size`. I know IE8 doesn't support `background-size` so its being ignored, but this means that my icon positioning is incorrect.

Using javascript you can find out your current pixelratio:

```
alert(window.devicePixelRatio);
```

This alerts: `undefined` in Internet Explorer.
How come that my "retina media query" accepts `undefined` as a valid number, and executes its css? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good method to Void Responsive Web Design/Media Queries for IE 8 -?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914474/good-method-to-void-responsive-web-design-media-queries-for-ie-8)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the default value for devicePixelRatio, if it is undefined

```
window.devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1
```

Comment: I used the piece of javascript for debugging. I can't control my mixin   with it. The problem I have is that my retina media query thinks  `undefined` is a higher number then `1.5` so its css gets executed.

Comment: Maybe you can try this: `document.body.className += !(window.devicePixelRatio) || (window.devicePixelRatio <= 1)? ' no-retina': ' retina';`  in the script tag and wrap you scss selector  `.retina .selector {
  @include sprite-background(clock_small, 0px, 2px, 0px, -1013px, 45px);
}`