# Call a different style sheet only for ie8 with JavaScript (media queries not supported)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, screen-resolution

I need to call different style sheets for different resolutions only for IE8, as it's not compatible with media queries.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: This deals with the conditional css, but not with the different resolutions. It needs to be a combination of <!--[if IE 8]> and <link media="screen and (max-width: ...px)" href="xxxx.css"> but I can't make it work either

Comment: Ahmed's original question said nothing about different resolutions. In fact, the original question was "Call a different css style sheet only for ie8 with java script JavaScript (media queries not supported)" conditional CSS works fine to answer the original question.

Comment: Original: "call different css only for ie8 on different resolution without media queries"

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**: I messed this answer up by getting it mixed up with another question but all should be well now. Sorry OP.

---

Instead of having separate stylesheets for each resolution, combine them and have javascript place a class on the Body so that the right style rules for a resolution are applied. **e.g.,**:

IE8Styles.css

```
.mystyle { /* Common Styles */ }
body.res800x600 .mystyle { ... }
body.res1024x768 .mystyle { ... }
```

Page.html

```
<script>
setTimeout(fixResolutionStyles, 200)

function fixResolutionStyles() {
    var windowWidth = document.body.offsetWidth
    var bodyClass = ""
    if(windowWidth > 1600){
        bodyClass = '1600x900'
    } else if (windowWidth > 1024) {
        bodyClass = '1024x786'
    }
    document.body['class'] = "res" + bodyClass
    setTimeout(fixResolutionStyles, 200)
}
</script>
```

Comment: [CSS classes must begin with an underscore, dash or letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) to be valid.

Comment: Right, but a selector for a class begins with a period. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Durr, I see it :( ok will fix

Comment: Class names that begin with numbers (the 'dot' is really just [shorthand notation for `div[class~=value]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) and doesn't count as part of the name) are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expressly asking "with javascript" I won't advocate the use of [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
That leaves [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/121hztk3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version == 5.8)
document.getElementById("id-of-your-style-tag").styleSheet.addImport("/path/style.css");
@end@*/
```