# How to detect wrapping on the next line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu (.navigation) that I would like to hide instead of wrapping on next line if the screen width is small. But I can't figure out how to use javascript/jQuery to detect if the wrapping has occurred (and hide the navigation).

I cannot use media query becase it is based on specific width when the navigation will be collapsed.

How can i solve this?

```css
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.navigation {
  float: right;
}

.navigation a {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  COMPANY LOGO
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About us</a>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use [media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796297/div-show-hide-media-query) and resize the browser and test where the wrapping happens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide div element when screen size is smaller than a specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476267/hide-div-element-when-screen-size-is-smaller-than-a-specific-size)

Comment: I cannot use this solution because it is based on the exact width of the screen when the navigation is hidden. But I don't know how many links will be in the navigation because the user adds them himself through the CMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you must, you can use basic javascript:

```
if (window.innerWidth < yourNumber) {
    // hide navigation class
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to calculate yourNumber.

Comment: Well that is something that depends on your container width, logo width and in the end the width of you navigation `document.querySelector('.navigation').offsetWidth`
with those numbers you should calculate when you can hide the element