# How can flexbox items be removed?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can flexbox items be removed on wrapper shrink? For example, YouTube removes elements when shrinking the window without wrapping them to the next line. [Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjQvf.png) So that the video containers do not go down when compressed and do not move the lower container, but are simply removed. So that there is no such thing as on the 2nd screen
enter image description here[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhyER.png)

Comment: you can use a media Query to hide the parts of the item you don't need under a specific screen size

Comment: They use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to hide elements based on viewport [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width) (not screen size).

Comment: yup, wrong expression from my end, thanks ^^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide div element when screen size is smaller than a specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476267/hide-div-element-when-screen-size-is-smaller-than-a-specific-size)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways you can achieve it by simply using *media queries* and *overflow hidden*. Don't forget the *flex-shrink*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 12px;
  /* IMPORTANT */
  overflow: hidden;
}

section article {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  /* IMPORTANT */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit
}

/* IMPORTANT */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section article {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* IMPORTANT */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  section article {
    width: 33%;
  }
}

/* IMPORTANT */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  section article {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article style="background-color: blue">1</article>
  <article style="background-color: orange">2</article>
  <article style="background-color: green">3</article>
  <article style="background-color: pink">4</article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the YouTube analogy. There are 2 rows of videos, when we reduce the screen, the boxes go to the next row, but they do not move Shorts box

Comment: answer is a comment