# HTML 5 - HTML not seeing CSS in IE7/IE8?

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I have created a website using HTML 5 with resolution tags for a wide and medium layout. When testing my website I found that it works in IE9, chrome, firefox, safari but not IE8 and older. The CSS links I have used are below;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 900px)' href='medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href='wide.css' />
```

Currently upon opening the website, it has no divs or styling therefore I believe it has something to do with linking to the CSS style sheets. I have used div tags within my html;

Example:

```
<div id ="container">
    <div id ="header">
        <div id = "logo">
            <img src="images/Logo.jpg" height = "180" width = "300" alt = "Oops!">
        </div>                
        <div id = "small-logo">
            <img src="images/SmallLogo.jpg" alt = "Oops!">
        </div>        
    </div>
```

I am not an expert and any information would be extremely helpful.

EDIT:

I have tried using:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script >
<script type='text/javascript' src='resolution-test.js'></script>
```

Using javascript:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
  width = parseInt(width);
  if (width < 900) {
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "medium.css");
  } else {
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "wide.css"); 
  }
}

$(function() {
  adjustStyle($(this).width());
  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
  });
});
```

The webpage is now only seeing the style sheet? Are there any problems with this code?

Comment: [IE8 support for CSS Media Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query).

Comment: Can you add a complete code sample with the head and body?

Comment: @Vucko Not true.  Many features of CSS3 won't work in IE8 or older, but that wouldn't stop all styles from rendering.  Also, LaurenA didn't specify CSS3.

Comment: @Maloric yes I know, I was thinking of _media-querys_, but I wrote wrong. I edited the comment.

Comment: FYI : SEO Speaking, your `alt`s should not be oops but something that descripes the photo.

Comment: Looks like Vucko hit the nail on the head - the media query seems the most obvious culprit.

Comment: @eric.itzhak this a prototype website, its not completely finished and is being used as an educational project.

Comment: @Vucko I am using CCS 3/HTML 5. Is there any javascript to use that would enable it to be backward compatible to IE8 and older?

Comment: @LaurenA I personally use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

Answer (score 3):

You are using [CSS3 media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) inside the media attributes of your link tags, [they are not supported by IE8 and older versions](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries). That would be the reason why the stylesheets aren't loading in IE8 and older.

**Edit**

As mentioned in [the answer by Colin Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16459828/1846192) below, you can use [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/) to make things work for you. I'm just adding it here as you seem to be overlooking the mentioned option. All you would need to do is add the following line in your head section preceding your link tags (replace the `src` attribute value with the path to your hosted copy of respond.js):

```
<script src="/path/to/respond.proxy.js"></script>
```

And things will start working for you from IE6 up to IE8, it is by far the easiest fix for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by other answers, CSS3 media queries are not supported in IE8 and below. If you need them to work you can use this polyfill by Scott Jehl.

[Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 media queries are not supported in IE8 and lower.

check this support matrix:

http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Answer (score 0):

Media queries were not supported in IE before version 9 but you can use IE conditional comments to specify an additional stylesheet that would be loaded in older versions of IE:

e.g.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="old-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

However you cannot specify the screen size in these comments, but you could have some Javascript that detects the screen size and loads the correct stylesheet (ideally the script would be in an alternative file) e.g.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width< 901) { 
        document.write('<link href="medium.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>');
    } else { 
        document.write('<link href="wide.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>');
    }
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I have tried to use an external javascript file.. I have updated my question to show what i've used. It still isn't seeing the style sheets medium.css and wide.css. Are there any problems with the code i have used?

Comment: Have you declared a 'style' element with Id of 'size-stylesheet' as that is what the jQuery code is looking for.

Comment: Also reloading the CSS whenever the resize event is called would be quite inefficient, you could store the window size whenever the resize event is handled and only reload the CSS when the size moves above/below 900px.

Comment: Also the resolution-test.js and <style id="size-stylesheet" ...> should only be refereneced in the conditional comments so that they're only loaded in IE7/IE8 and the media query based style declarations are used otherwise

Comment: The respond.js solution recommended by Colin Bacon looks like it would be a simpler solution