# How to ensure that elements are properly aligned even when window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage aligned properly when viewed fullscreen in a browser, but when the same is resized things go horribly mis-aligned.
Here's the html.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
  textarea {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    font-size:20;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 450px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  #chatArea {
    width:600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  h1
  {
    text-align: center;
    width:600px;
    margin-left:280px;
    margin-right:20px;
    color: brown;
  }
  .greyText
  {
    color:grey;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Suggestion Box</h1>
<div id="chatArea">
<textarea id='chatHistory' value="Type your suggestion here." ></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<form id= 'chatForm' onsubmit="return false">
    <input name= 'newMessageString' id="newMessageString" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value='send'/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make sure that however the page is resized the elements stay at the center?

Comment: How many pixels is "fullscreen"? 1024? 1280?

Comment: @mediaqueries, floats, percentages. Or use a responsive grid. Welcome to the world of supporting 10000000 resolutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, what should I do?

Comment: You should look for "responsive" web development, or "mobile", or "adaptive", or "fluid"... there are many approaches to the same problem.

Comment: Take a look to http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: You can also try adapting one of these: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width of your textarea to `600px` to fill the entire centered `#chatArea` div and center your `h1` by changing its margins to:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
  textarea {
    height:500px;
    width:600px;
    font-size:20;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 450px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  #chatArea {
    width:600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  h1
  {
    text-align: center;
    width:600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: brown;
  }
  .greyText
  {
    color:grey;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Suggestion Box</h1>
<div id="chatArea">
<textarea id='chatHistory' value="Type your suggestion here." ></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<form id= 'chatForm' onsubmit="return false">
    <input name= 'newMessageString' id="newMessageString" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value='send'/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at responsive design

There are a lot of FW that can help like

- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

And all are based on **media queries** `@media(max-width:1023px)` , this is not supported in IE8 you can take a look at [IE8 support for CSS Media Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query)
OR use http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

**Edit**

I forget to tell you that most of the `widths` are percent like `34.333%`

I hope this can help and put you on the right track

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code :

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
  textarea {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    font-size:20;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 450px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  #chatArea {
    text-align:center;
    width:600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  h1
  {
    text-align: center;
    color: brown;
  }
  .greyText
  {
    color:grey;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

<div id="chatArea">
<h1>Suggestion Box</h1><textarea id="chatHistory" value="Type your suggestion here."></textarea>
<br><br>
<form id="chatForm" onsubmit="return false">
    <input name="newMessageString" id="newMessageString" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</div>

`</body></html>
```

Comment: You accidentally left in `cz-shortcut-listen="true"` which is added by the Colorzilla Chrome extension.

Comment: He's wrapping your content in a container (using your #chatArea div - note he moved your h1 into #chatArea) which has a css margin: 10px auto ... This technique is described generically in my answer below.  the "auto" is what does it - that basically centers your element as long as the container is smaller than the window.

Answer (score 1):

you can use percentages to acomodate your layout on the browser take a look at the changes i made http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/

```
 <style type='text/css'>
              textarea {
                height:500px;
                width:500px;
                font-size:20;
                font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
              }
              input[type="text"] {
                width: 450px;
                height: 30px;
              }
              #chatArea {
                width:80%;
                margin: 10px auto;
                display:block;
                text-align:center;
              }
              h1
              {
                text-align: center;
                width:80%;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                color: brown;
              }
              .greyText
              {
                color:grey;
              }
            </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The general approach for this is to wrap your body content in a fixed-width container with left & right margins set to "auto" to center the content.

ie

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--the rest of your content goes here-->
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:960px; /* or whatever width you would like to set */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I think discussions about various responsive frameworks etc. are a bit out of scope here - this is a rather elementary question.  Move on to that stuff once you learn the basics.