# How to hide a 'div" in jquery for ie8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

http://neeyamo.com/

the above website displays hidden layouts in ie8.
Which are meant to display only in low screen resolution.
i used "display:none" using css media query.
It works fine in other browsers.
But in IE8, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use $("#idofdiv").hide() in jquery in document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

Css media queries are not supported by IE8 but there are ways to get around [IE7, IE8 support for css3 media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205253/ie7-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
/*
.yourclass { display: none; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```