# angular ui modal in ie

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, user-interface, width

I am using angular ui modal in a project. 
The whole fun0ctionality like with modal is working in all browsers even in ie. The width which i am specifying to modal body is working fine in chrome,mozilla and safari  but its not working in ie (that modal is taking the whole sceen size width expanding through the screen).
what to do

this is in my html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="exitApp.html">

        <div class="modal-header" >
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12- col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row" >
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">

                                <span>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ic_launcher.png" alt=""  height="91" width="101" style="margin-left:2%"> 
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2 " "><span ><h2 >Appetite</h2></span></div> 
                        </div>  

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="ddpanel" style="margin-left:7%;" >
                    <h2 >Do you wish to exit from the application ?</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="ok()">yes</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="cancel()">No</button>

        </div>
</script>
```

i have just changed the modal dialog width and  some other styles according to my requirements

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 35%;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .modal-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

That width 35% is not working in ie

Is there any other possibility to make it differently work in ie.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that IE doesn't recognize your CSS media query. Here's another StackOverflow post that might help you: [IE7, IE8 support for css3 media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205253/ie7-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query)

Comment: It worked after including css3mediaquiries javascript file ..thanksss