# Unable to redefine bootstrap col-md width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, column-width, grid-system

I am trying to redefine the width of col-md-4. If I go directly to the bootstrap file and edit the code below, it works. But when I open a new css file and put in the codes below and redefine the width, it does not work. Why? The problem I am trying to solve is because in IE7, I have 2 items in a row instead of 3, so I am trying to reduce the width by redefining it, so that 3 items will be on a row. Perhaps there are other suggestions?

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more specific selector would be applied. You can read more from [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

For your case, you can rewrite the rules to be more specific or by adding an `!important` tag for the attribute.

```
.col-md-4.wide { /* Or another more specific selector */
```

OR

```
width: 33.33333333% !important;
```

Comment: I tried using .col-md-4 span{} and putting the !important, but it still does not work. Perhaps the problem lies with using this 2 js files http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9. This 2 js files is to make Boostrap support IE. I am sure you have heard of them?

Comment: If your elements were `span`, please use `span.col-md-4` selector.

Comment: It works now when I had @media (min-width: 992px) {} removed! Now both ways you mentioned works! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Seems that your problem is more related to this question then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205253/ie7-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query