# media queries not working inside IE hacks

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I have a IE hack problem where I need to add media queries specifically for IE7(IE8 is working fine). I am using respond.js also. So when i do something like this:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
            <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
.abc{width: 100px !important;}

}

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

IE7 doesnot understand it. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE in general hardly understands css. Good luck with IE7!! But i'm not here just to joke. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205253/ie7-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query)

Comment: IE7 hardly understands html

Comment: `<!--[if IE]>` isn't really a "hack", it just means only old IE builds will actually read it. It doesn't magically provide support for newer CSS properties :(

Comment: why do you need media support for IE old browsers? I see no reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries do not work below IE8. But take a look at these plugins and tutorials about how to support media queries in IE8 and below:

### css3-mediaqueries-js

- [Tutorial](http://cssmatter.com/blog/ie7-and-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query/)
- [Plugin website](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)

### Respond.js

- [Plugin website](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Answer (score 0):

Actully IE8 and lower version doesn't support Media Query
For IE9 we can use this

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```