# @media print doesn't work in IE 8,7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I googled in here, and tried to print only the div's i want.

used this,

```
@media print
{
    #top_area { display: none; }
    #left_area { display: none; }
    #buttom_area { display: none; }
    #contents_area { display: block; }
}
```

and it works fine in chrome and over IE9.

But the problem is under IE8.

It just immediately shutdowns the browser :(

Any good solution?

Comment: it is typical ie, try with javascript

Comment: well if i use javascript, has a problem with the CSS :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows Internet Explorer 9 introduces support for media queries.**  That is why it is not working for you in IE 8

Comment: So what should i do in IE8 :(

Comment: As per my knowledge no way to do it in IE 8 or below versions using media css

Comment: let me tell you that in IE+ 8 it does work. See my post.

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer versions before IE9 **do not support media queries**.

If you're using the `@media print` directive to provide a print stylesheet to modern browsers, you can take advantage of [Internet Explorer's conditional comments](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) to target specific versions of IE and deliver a print stylesheet to them. You will, of course, need to have a separate `print.css` for these versions of IE to consume.

For example, in your HTML's `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This code snippet says, "if I am a version of Internet Explorer BEFORE IE9, use this print stylesheet". Versions of IE9 and up will not use this stylesheet.

This way, modern browsers that understand the `@media` directive get the benefit of not having an additional http request for the print stylesheet, while providing a fallback for browsers that do not support `@media`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in IE8. Possible workarounds are suggested at [IE8 support for CSS Media Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query). Hope this helps. :-)