# Double image height bootstrap IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

Why IE8 makes images double height? Can't find way to fix it. Please help:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media queries don't work in IE8 and below.

Have a look here to browse for possible solutions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query)

In your case, you could probably go the other way around and build the site for desktop resolution and use the media queries to make the page fit a mobile display. That way, it will work in old browsers and all phone browser will know media queries.