# Foundation 5 top-bar (dropdown) not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

I'm struggling to get the Foundation 5 top-bar dropdown working in IE8.

I was wondering if anyone has come up with a solution for this.

Having a quick Google I found this but it didn't seem to work when I tried it - https://gist.github.com/tmayr/5190565

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Well, look at the FAQ -> http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html, more precisely the first section : "**1. Why doesn't Foundation support IE7 or IE8? Or: why we don't support a dying species.**"

Comment: Sure, I understand that. I was just wondering if anyone knows a way to get it working in IE8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 support for CSS Media Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query)

Comment: there is a 100 questions about foundation ie8 support issues and its not supported

Comment: @davidkonrad someone should 'fix' with fire all the recent questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation+internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 0):

- Foundation 5 requires jQuery 2
- jQuery 2 does not work on IE 8 or less, must use IE 9 or better
- Revert to F3 and jQ1 for IE8 support