# Why does my site look different in IE 8 and lower?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is my site http://tholexos.nl/

But in IE 8 or lower it looks like garbage. Why is this?? My navigation goes immiediatly to mobile version and the actual menu is getting in the footer...

I know IE has some bugs but I don`t know what bugs are causing this problem for my site. I am asking you guys if you want to help my find the problem.

Thnx for the help!

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html xml:lang="nl-NL" lang="nl-NL" class="ie ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html xml:lang="nl-NL" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (lt IE 8)|(gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!--><html xml:lang="nl-NL" lang="nl-NL"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png"/>
<meta name="description" content="Onze visie als bedrijf bestaat uit het faciliteren van kinderen samen met hun ouders om zich zo goed mogelijk voor te bereiden op de verplichte rekentoets. Door het hoofdrekenen op een ouderwetse manier">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<p id="payoff"><span>l</span></p>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">

<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!--><link rel="stylesheet" href="abc.css" type="text/css"/><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)|(IE 8)]><link rel="stylesheet" href="abc.css" type="text/css" media="screen,print" /><![endif]-->
<title>Tholexos - Home</title>

</head>

<body id="government">
<base target="_blank">
<div id="centerbox">
    <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html" target="_self"  title="Naar de homepage van Rijksoverheid.nl">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Tholexos.nl"/>
    </a>
    <div class="skiplinks">
    <p>
        <span class="assistive">Ga direct naar</span>
        <a title="Navigeer naar de inhoud" href="#content">
            Inhoud</a>
        <span class="assistive">of</span>
        <a id="skip-to-menu" class="active" title="Navigeer naar het hoofdmenu" href="#navigation">
            Menu</a>
    </p>

</div><div id="search">

</div></div>


<!--[if lt IE 7]><p><strong>Rijksoverheid.nl omarmt moderne standaarden en technieken.</strong><br/>Uw webbrowser (Microsoft IE6) ondersteunt deze standaarden niet. Stap daarom over op een recente browser.</p><![endif]--><div id="main">

    <div class="header">

    <p id="breadcrumb">

</p><span class="assistive">Onderwerp: </span>
<!--<a id="topic-home" href="#"><span>Taal en rekenen</span></a><p class="assistive">Dit onderwerp bevat 1 rubrieken.</p>-->
        <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="selected">
                <a href="#" target="_self">Visie</a>
                </li>

        </ul>
</div><!--<div class="decorative">
        <img src="#" alt=""

                    title="Foto: Hollandse Hoogte."
                 />
    </div>-->
<div class="background2"></div>
<div id="contentr" class="article">
<div class="textindex">
Onze visie als bedrijf bestaat uit het faciliteren van kinderen samen met hun ouders om zich zo goed mogelijk voor te bereiden op de verplichte rekentoets. Door het hoofdrekenen op een ouderwetse manier en op een verantwoordelijke en getoetste leermethode, te kunnen oefenen op een modern apparaat, dat eenvoudig voor handen is en laagdrempelig in gebruik. 
<br>
<br>
<h2>Ouderwets oefenen in een nieuw jasje! - reken op je toekomst!</h2>
</div><div class="img1"><img src="logo_met.png" alt="Reken op je toekomst!"/></div>

    <!--<h1>Extra maatregelen rekenonderwijs voortgezet onderwijs en middelbaar beroepsonderwijs</h1>
<div class="lead">

  <p>Het rekenonderwijs is nog niet op orde. Leerlingen mogen daar niet de dupe van worden. Daarom voert de Rijksoverheid een aantal extra maatregelen in het voortgezet onderwijs en het middelbaar beroepsonderwijs in.</p>  
 </div>
<h2>Voorbeelden extra maatregelen</h2>

  <p>De extra maatregelen staan in de <a href="#">kamerbrief Stand van zaken invoering referentieniveaus taal en rekenen in vo en mbo</a>. Voorbeelden van maatregelen zijn:</p> 
  <ul> 
   <li>Een overgangsperiode waarin leerlingen geen cijfer krijgen, maar een vaardigheidsscore (voldoende of onvoldoende). De overgangsperiode duurt 4 jaar. </li> 
   <li>Aangepaste toetsen voor leerlingen die zwak zijn in rekenen.</li> 
   <li>Entree-basisdiploma in de entreeopleiding en een vakdiploma in mbo-2.</li> 
   <li>Nieuwe regels voor de doorstroom van leerlingen.</li> 
   <li>Docenten mogen de rekentoetsen na afloop inzien.</li> 
  </ul> 
  <p>Het doel is zorgen dat zoveel mogelijk leerlingen het referentieniveau voor rekenen halen.</p>  
 <div class="content-image-left">
        <img src="#" alt="Infographic over Rekenen op orde in 2020. Kijk voor een uitgebreide uitleg in het onderwerp: http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen"

                    title="Ministerie van OCW"

        />
        </div>
<h2>Overgangsperiode met vaardigheidsscores in plaats van cijfers</h2>

  <p>Tijdens een overgangsperiode van 4 jaar werken scholen en instellingen met vaardigheidsscores in plaats van cijfers. Leerlingen moeten minimaal een bepaalde vaardigheidsscore behalen om een �voldoende� voor het onderdeel rekenen te halen.</p> 
  <p>In het 1e jaar van de overgangsperiode krijgt een leerling een voldoende als hij een vaardigheidsscore haalt die gelijkstaat aan het cijfer 4,5. Daarna gaat de vaardigheidsscore elk jaar omhoog (opklimmende slaagcesuur). In het 4e jaar moet de vaardigheidsscore minimaal gelijk zijn aan het cijfer 5,5. Als blijkt dat er toch nog teveel leerlingen zakken voor de rekentoets, wordt de vaardigheidsscore weer aangepast, zodat er in het eerste jaar maximaal 5% van de studenten zakt.</p> 
  <p>De overgangsperiode gaat in tijdens het schooljaar waarin de <a href="#">rekentoets gaat meetellen voor het diploma</a>. Dit verschilt per schoolsoort.&nbsp;</p>  
 <h2>Aangepaste toesten voor leerlingen die zwak zijn in rekenen</h2>

  <p>Leerlingen die moeite hebben met rekenen, krijgen speciale rekentoetsen:</p> 
  <ul> 
   <li>de 2A toets voor leerlingen in het vmbo-bb, de entreeopleiding en mbo-2 die zwak zijn in rekenen;</li> 
   <li>ER-toetsen voor leerlingen met ERWD (ernstige reken-wiskundeproblemen en dyscalculie).</li> 
  </ul> 
  <p>Deze aangepaste toetsen zorgen ervoor dat leerlingen die alle andere vakken hebben gehaald, meer kans hebben om ook het onderdeel rekenen te halen. Zo kunnen ze hun diploma en startkwalificatie halen.</p> 
  <p>Scholen bieden leerlingen in het vmbo-bb en het mbo-2 altijd eerst de reguliere rekentoets aan. Als deze toets voor een leerling niet haalbaar is, kan de school de leerling een aangepaste toets laten maken. Dit gebeurt altijd in overleg met de leerling.&nbsp;</p>  
 <h2>Entree-basisdiploma in het mbo</h2>

  <p>De <a href="/onderwerpen/middelbaar-beroepsonderwijs/opleidingen-niveaus-en-leerwegen-in-het-mbo/entreeopleiding-in-het-mbo">entreeopleiding in het mbo</a> krijgt een entree-basisdiploma. Dit diploma is voor leerlingen die alle beroepsspecifieke onderdelen van de entreeopleiding hebben gehaald, maar (nog) niet kunnen voldoen aan de eisen voor rekenen (of taal). Leerlingen die willen doorstromen van de entreeopleiding naar mbo-2, moeten aan dezelfde eisen voor taal en rekenen voldoen als leerlingen in het vmbo-bb. Als zij aan deze eisen voldoen, krijgen zij een entree-doorstroomdiploma.</p>  
 <h2>Nieuwe regels voor doorstroom van leerlingen</h2>

  <p>Om te kunnen doorstromen naar een vervolgopleiding moeten leerlingen aan bepaalde eisen voldoen. Hier horen straks ook de eisen voor taal en rekenen bij. </p> 
  <ul> 
   <li><h3> Doorstromen naar mbo-3 </h3> Dit kan alleen met referentieniveau 2F. De aangepaste 2A toets is hiervoor dus niet voldoende.</li> 
   <li><h3> Doorstromen van voortgezet onderwijs naar mbo </h3> Leerlingen die in het voortgezet onderwijs een ER-toets hebben gemaakt, kunnen alle opleidingen in het mbo volgen. Ook in het mbo mogen ze een ER-toets maken. Een ER-toets is bedoeld voor kinderen met ERWD (ernstige reken-wiskundeproblemen en dyscalculie).</li> 
   <li><h3>Doorstromen naar het hoger onderwijs </h3> Iedereen met het juiste diploma kan naar het hoger onderwijs kan. Dus ook leerlingen die een diploma hebben gehaald met de ER-toets.</li> 
   <li><h3>Doorstromen naar de pabo </h3> Voor leerlingen die naar de pabo willen doorstromen geldt een uitzondering. Zij moeten de reguliere 3F toets taal en rekenen gehaald hebben. Anders hebben zij niet de vaardigheden die nodig zijn om goed rekenonderwijs te geven aan hun leerlingen.</li> 
  </ul>  
 <div class="block docs-pubs">
        <h2>
                Documenten en publicaties</h2>

            <ul class="common">
                <li>
                            <a href="/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/documenten-en-publicaties/kamerstukken/2014/12/17/kamerbrief-invoering-referentieniveaus-taal-en-rekenen-in-vo-en-mbo.html" class="publication">
                                <h3>Kamerbrief invoering referentieniveaus taal en rekenen in vo en mbo</h3>
                                <p>Minister Bussemaker en staatssecretaris Dekker (OCW) informeren de Tweede Kamer over de stand van zaken van de invoering van de ...</p>
                                <p class="meta">
    Kamerstuk | 17-12-2014</p></a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/documenten-en-publicaties/publicaties/2014/12/17/2020-rekenen-op-orde.html" class="publication">
                                <h3>2020: rekenen op orde</h3>
                                <p>Infographic over Rekenen op orde in 2020. Het rekenonderwijs wordt de komende jaren verbeterd. De rekentoets groeit stap voor stap ...</p>
                                <p class="meta">
    Publicatie | 17-12-2014</p></a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/documenten-en-publicaties/publicaties/2014/12/17/doorstroming-naar-vervolgonderwijs.html" class="publication">
                                <h3>Doorstroming naar vervolgonderwijs</h3>
                                <p>Doorstroom: wat heb je nodig voor welk diploma en welke vervolgopleiding?</p>
                                <p class="meta">
    Publicatie | 17-12-2014</p></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>-->
</div><!--<div id="aside">
    <div class="block">
        <h2>Verder in dit onderwerp</h2>
        <ul class="common">
            <li>
                    <a href="/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/referentiekader-taal-en-rekenen">Referentieniveaus taal en rekenen</a>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <a href="/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/toetsen-examens-taal-en-rekenen">Toetsen en examens voor taal en rekenen</a>
                </li>
            <li>
                    <a href="/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/taal-en-rekenen-op-lerarenopleidingen">Taal en rekenen op de pabo</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
<div class="block">
        <h2>Zie ook</h2>
        <ul class="common">
        <li>
                            <a 
                                class="news"
                                    title="Nieuwsbericht | 17-12-2014"
                                    href="/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/nieuws/2014/12/17/rekenen-stap-voor-stap-beter.html">
                                Rekenen stap voor stap beter</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</div>
<div class="block banner">
        <a href="/contact">
            <img src="//roimg.nl/bestanden/afbeeldingen/banners/postbus-51/banner-inforijksoverh-ond.jpg" alt="Vragen? Bel Informatie Rijksoverheid: 1400"  />
        </a>
    </div>
<div class="block">
    <h2>Verantwoordelijk ministerie</h2>
    <ul class="common">
        <li>
                <a href="/ministeries/ocw" >
                            Ministerie van Onderwijs, Cultuur en Wetenschap</a>
                    </li>
        </ul>
</div></div>--><div id="follow-up">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="notifications"><!--
        <h2>Taal en rekenen: blijf op de hoogte</h2>
        <ul class="common">
            <li>
                                <a class="email" href="http://abonneren.rijksoverheid.nl/e-mailattenderingen/aanmelden/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/nieuws">
                                    Nieuwsberichten via e-mail</a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                                <a class="email" href="http://abonneren.rijksoverheid.nl/e-mailattenderingen/aanmelden/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/documenten-en-publicaties">
                                    Documenten en publicaties via e-mail</a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                                <a class="rss-feed" href="http://feeds.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/nieuws.rss">
                                    Nieuwsberichten via rss</a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                                <a class="rss-feed" href="http://feeds.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/taal-en-rekenen/documenten-en-publicaties.rss">
                                    Documenten en publicaties via rss</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul> -->
    </div>

<div class="sharing">
    <h2>Deel deze pagina op:</h2>
    <ul class="common">
      <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?;text=Tholexos+is+een+startup+die+zich+bezig+houdt+met+het+volgen,+trainen,+en+coachen+van+kinderen+voor+een+succesvolle+overstap+naar+het+voortgezetonderwijs+@tholexos+http://www.tholexos.nl/" target="_blank" class="twitter" title="Deel deze pagina op Twitter">
          <img src="twitter_logo.png" class="logo_grootte"/>Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.tholexos.nl/" target="_blank" class="facebook" title="Deel deze pagina op Facebook">
          <img src="facebook_logo.png" class="logo_grootte"/>Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=Tholexos%20is%20een%20startup%20die%20zich%20bezig%20houdt%20met%20het%20volgen,%20trainen,%20en%20coachen%20van%20kinderen%20voor%20een%20succesvolle%20overstap%20naar%20het%20voortgezetonderwijs%20%23Thlexos%20http://www.tholexos.nl/&title=&summary=&source=" target="_blank" class="linkedin" title="Deel deze pagina op LinkedIn">
          <img src="linkedin_logo.png" class="logo_grootte"/>LinkedIn</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.tholexos.nl/" target="_blank" class="google-plus" title="Deel deze pagina op Google+">
          <img src="google_logo.png" class="logo_grootte"/> Google+</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=http://www.tholexos.nl/" target="_blank" class="tumblr" title="Deel deze pagina op Tumblr">
          <img src="tumblr_logo.png" class="logo_grootte"/>Tumblr</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div id="sitemap">
    <h2>
        Informatie over rekenen:
            </h2>

    <div>
        <ul class="common column">
                <li>
                        <a href="http://www.taalenrekenen.nl/ref_niveaus_rekenen/">Referentieniveaus taal en rekenen</a>
                        </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="http://www.rekenhulp-basisschool-pabo.nl">Rekenhulp voor ouders en anderen</a>


                        </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="http://slo.nl">Nationaal expertisecentrum leerplanontwikkeling</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>

    </div>
</div></div><div id="logofooter"></div>
<div id="navigation" class="block">
<!--         ------------                   hier is bovenste nav                       -------------               -->   
   <h2>Hoofdnavigatie</h2>
   <ul>
        <li class="selected2"><a href="index.html" target="_self" >Home</a></li>
        <li class="selected1"><a href="over_tholexos.html" target="_self" >Over Tholexos</a></li>
        <li class="selected1"><a href="blog.html" target="_self" >Blog</a></li>
        <li class="selected1"><a href="contact.html" target="_self" >Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

    </div>
<div id="footer" class="three-column">
    <div class="background">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="footer_lijn"></div>
        <h2>Over deze site</h2>
        <ul>
                <div class="text"><li class="center-li"><a href="over_tholexos.html" target="_self" >Over Tholexos.nl</a></li>
                <li class="center-li"><a href="disclaimer.html" target="_self" >Disclaimer</a></li>
                <li class="center-li"><a href="http://rekenopjetoekomst.nl/">Rekenopjetoekomst.nl is een handelsnaam van Tholexos</a><li>
                <li class="center-li"><a>&#169; 2015 Tholexos - Reken op je toekomst</a></li>
                </ul>

        </div>
</div></div>

</div></div>

<script src="core-14.7.1.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

For the css script you get here --> http://tholexos.nl/abc.css

Comment: IE has always struggled with css rules. Period. Do anything fancy, and you're gonna struggle with IE. Even basic styling is enough to hurt it.

Comment: Wait... what?!? `<!--[if (lt IE 8)|(gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!--><html xml:lang="nl-NL" lang="nl-NL"><!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: whats your problem?? I am trying so much...

Comment: One probably reason is your media queries, it does not work in IE8. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Comment: @ThomasPereira: Look into [this](http://caniuse.com/) - if you use css styling, search here if you 'can use' it for IE8 and below. (Although, I do feel there should just be a list of 'what is acceptable of IE8' - it would be much shorter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support IE8 you should do the following 3 things. There may be others:

1) Set the DOCTYPE to HTML 4.01:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

2) Make sure all of your CSS is CSS2 compatible

3) Put your BASE tag inside of your HEAD

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using media queries in your abc.css stylesheet; IE8 doesn't support media queries - so if you have designed your site 'mobile first' I guess IE8 is defaulting to that look.

There are a few solutions if you search for 'IE8 media queries' such as mentioned on this thread:
[IE8 support for CSS Media Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query)