# How to determine variable window.width of screen.width to use in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I need to know the screen size in jQuery or JavaScript and I need this value printed in PHP variable that will determine whether or not an item is displayed.

```
var width = $(window).width();

if (width <= 1024) {
   ///// How can I set a variable here and use it with PHP?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: php does not know what a screen is

Comment: PHP is a server side language that creates a web page and spits it out to the browser. The browser can not communicate with the process that created the page. Therefore, PHP can not react to any javascript while generating the page. You'll need to hide/show the item in javascript alone

Comment: To re-iterate a comment on an answer - 
 
if I understand the question, an item needs to be included/excluded based on page width. As php creates the page without knowing the page width, by the time javascript determines the page width, PHP has finished creating the page and is no longer in a position to include/exclude anything ... so, sending page width to PHP can only help when creating the NEXT page, not the current page

Answer (score 0):

mate, you never get the window width from your php code, php code is executing on your web server, you can only get your window size from javascript which is working on user's browser, you just need find a way sending the width you got from js to your php code, that's it !

sample code :

```
function myJavascriptFunction() { 
  var javascriptVariable = "John";
  window.location.href = "YOURPHPFILE.php?name=" + javascriptVariable; 
}
```

Comment: if I understand the question, an item needs to be included/excluded based on page width. As php creates the page without knowing the page width, by the time javascript determines the page width, PHP has finished creating the page and is no longer in a position to include/exclude anything ... so, sending page width to PHP can only help when creating the NEXT page, not the current page

Comment: Thank you! I will try the way you said.

Comment: @Renata, cool, mate, dont forget to tick my answer, lol , happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking but please tell me if I didn't get it correctly.

An idea that came immediately to mind is where you gather the viewport width and height information as soon as possible and then reload the page but pass the viewport information variables through the URL and receive them in PHP.

Try this code for the suggestion above. Normally, you put your script in an onload function but in this case, you want the dimensions as soon as possible.

```
<script>
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
location = location+'?w='+width+'&h='+height;
</script>
```

The second option is that you can do something complicated with AJAX.
The third options is where you can use CSS media queries (as mentioned in the other answer[s]).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display elements based on the browser width, use [CSS media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and the `display:none;` property to hide elements.

Comment: [Stack Overflow says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query) that IE 8 or older will not understand media queries. Newer versions should do so thanks to CSS3 support.

Comment: so a (old IE specific) css/javascript alternative could be used for old IE using `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` etc

Comment: I think so, yes. Although you might have to accept some drawbacks when using "modern" CSS. On the other hand, IE 8 and older is really dying, so you might consider not putting that work in.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written in your question you have to check the correct width on the front-end side. You can use it jQuery or pure JS.

If you want to set some PHP variable and pass it to the PHP script then you have to use AJAX.

And again.. You can use it as a plain JS (`XMLHttpRequest` object) or `ajax` method from jQuery, like that:

**JS code:**

```
var variableForPHP = <?php echo 'some_value' ?>;

$.ajax({
   url: 'script.php',
   method: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {phpVariable: variableForPHP},
   success: function (respondFromPHP) {
     // do something after AJAX call
     console.log('respond from PHP: ' + respondFromPHP);
   }
});
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
  $variableFromAjax = $_POST['phpVariable'];    
  // do something
  var_dump($variableFromAjax);
  $respondToAjax = 'thanks for variable: '. $variableFromAjax;
  echo json_encode($respondToAjax);
?>
```