# IE8 - media query is not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've got very curious case in IE8 where media query is not working on URL (mobile view shows on desktop) but If I use IP address than it works (desktop view shows). I tried a whole lot of things even several solutions from stackoverflow but couldn't succeed. It seems like respond.js issue but I'm not sure. Can anyone please help me on this.

URL: https://www.uhc.com/

IP: 149.111.148.170

FYI: I'm using IE 11 developer Tool to check it on IE8.

Comment: Could be something to do with CSS file size?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support media queries.

Comment: E8 is out to date and doesn't support html5/css3

Comment: @ahevin I don't think css file size for an issue as it working good with IP https://149.111.148.170/

Comment: @all I'm using respond.js here to support media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

> I found the issue. It was due to analytics script. Hence closing this
>   question.

---

Answer (score 1):

**IE8** (and lower versions)  **do not support media query**.

and you can use **IE11/ EDGE BROWSER**

There are some workarounds that use JavaScript to add media query support to these browsers. Try these:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

learn more about it

**CSS Media Query not Supported in IE** 
 https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/css-media-query-not-supported-in-ie/

**IE7 and IE8 support for CSS3 Media Query**

http://cssmatter.com/blog/ie7-and-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query/

---

**A fast & lightweight polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries (for IE 6-8, and more)**
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Reference - **Stackoverflow**  [IE8 support for CSS Media Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query?rq=1)

Comment: I've checked both respond.js and css3-mediaquery js. Noting works in my situation.